# expanding partition: allocated space vs available space

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I do not want to destroy my vm :) I am new at linux (startup on a budget)

Here are my partitions:

```
 Filesystem                   Size     Used      Avail   Use%     Mounted on
 udev                         3.9G     0         3.9G    0%       /dev
 tmpfs                        798M     924K      797M    1%       /run
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root      4.6G     3.9G      442M    90%      /
 tmpfs                        3.9G     8.0K      3.9G    1%       /dev/shm
 tmpfs                        5.0M     0         5.0M    0%       /run/lock
 tmpfs                        3.9G     0         3.9G    0%       /sys/fs/cgroup
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu-tmp       453M     2.3M      423M    1%       /tmp
 /dev/sda1                    990M     145M      779M    16%      /boot
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu-home      1.8G     128M      1.6G    8%       /home
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu-var       2.7G     1.4G      1.2G    55%      /var
 tmpfs                        798M     0         798M    0%       /run/user/1000

 total                        24G      5.5G      18G     24%      -
```

When looking at my virtual disk sizes:

```
 H/W path           Device      Class      Description
 =====================================================
 /0/100/10/0.0.0    /dev/sda    disk       1073MB Virtual disk
 /0/100/10/0.1.0    /dev/sdb    disk       284GB Virtual disk
 /0/100/10/0.3.0    /dev/sdd    disk       107GB Virtual disk
```

It looks like I should have close to 400GB but my partition total shows 24G

I am nearly out of hard drive space on and need to expand this:

/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root      4.6G     3.9G      442M    90%      /

Am I reading the correct information and making the correct statement? How do I see what is on /dev/sdb? Is that just free space? How do I expand /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root?

Answer (score 0):

Due to not many views and activity I posted in another channel. I quickly received a response.

The answer can be found here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618097/expanding-partition-with-available-space